# How to get an iPOJO component instance configuration?

Tags: java, dictionary, configuration, components, ipojo

I have an iPOJO Component Instance that I create like this:

```
  Dictionary dic = new Hashtable();
  dic.put("target-name", finalHelloInstanceName);
  ComponentInstance x= factory.createComponentInstance(dic);
```

Inside my component that I am instantiating above, how can I get the Dictionary "dic" values?

Could it be something like?

```
@Validate
    public void start() throws Exception {

        Dictionary dic= ?????

}
```

or is it:

```
@Updated
public void updated(Dictionary conf) {

    dic= conf;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some experiments, and I found that, when I add the following method to my bundle:

```
@Updated
public void updated(Dictionary conf) {

    dic= conf;


}
```

this method will be invoked automatically once the component is instantiated, receiving my instance configuration. I also noticed that this method is invoked before the start() method of the bundle. Nice stuff!